# Unable to install PIP on Windows 10 - Python 2.7

Tags: installation, powershell, python, pip

I am attempting to install PIP on my Windows 10 Laptop. I have attempted to install it using Command Prompt and PowerShell.

I go to https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py, copy it, paste it, then run the command:

`python get-pip.py`.

The installation stops right after `Installing collected packages: pip, setuptools, wheel`. The error that comes up is:

`Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\users\\cborch~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-install-haochd\\pip\\pip\\CredDB2.CEF'`